# C# MessageBox with ComboBox doesn't works

Tags: c#, if-statement, combobox, messagebox

The last `MessageBox` with the error message doesn't work; the program just crashes. I want to use the `MessageBox` to show the user that they forgot to select one of the items: Mountenbike, Rennrad, or Faltrad.

```
if (typen.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Mountenbike")
{
    mb = new Mountenbike(artikelNr, name, ekPreis, vkPreis);
    mbCounter++;
    MessageBox.Show("Fertig");
}
else if (typen.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Rennrad")
{
    rr = new Rennrad(artikelNr, name, ekPreis, vkPreis);
    rrCounter++;
    MessageBox.Show("Fertig");
}
else if (typen.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Faltrad")
{
    fr = new Faltrad(artikelNr, name, ekPreis, vkPreis);
    frCounter++;
    MessageBox.Show("Fertig");
}
else if (typen.SelectedItem == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error - Please enter xyz");
}
```

Comment: What is the exception thrown? Also `null` check should come first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably getting an exception because you can't instantiate the method `ToString()` on a null reference, assuming by your last `else if` statement that the value of `typen.SelectedItem` can potentially be null if nothing is selected.

You should check whether the value of `typen.SelectedItem` is `null` first before instantiating any methods against it. That can be done simply as:

```
if (typen.SelectedItem == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error - Please enter xyz");
    return;
}

if (typen.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Mountenbike")
{
    mb = new Mountenbike(artikelNr, name, ekPreis, vkPreis);
    mbCounter++;
    MessageBox.Show("Fertig");
}
else if (typen.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Rennrad")
{
    rr = new Rennrad(artikelNr, name, ekPreis, vkPreis);
    rrCounter++;
    MessageBox.Show("Fertig");
}
else if (typen.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Faltrad")
{
    fr = new Faltrad(artikelNr, name, ekPreis, vkPreis);
    frCounter++;
    MessageBox.Show("Fertig");
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!! I'd upvote it if I'd be able to ._. // You are really awesome you saved me!! ^.^

Comment: One question, stackoverflow is really confusing me. How can I get reuptation points? I can't help anyone because I'm still a Noob, but I want to upvote good answers. Are here any forum games where I can get reputation

Comment: The easiest way to get rep is to ask good quality questions and answer questions where you can share your knowledge. See the "What is Reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?" article in the [help], and check out the [tour] as well (you'll get a badge for your troubles!)